# Android Material design error validation does not appear

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android

When I add an error message to the edit text.

I see the icon, but the error message does not appear by default just after clicking on the icon

This is my layout text

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:hint="@string/enter_client_name">


                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    app:errorEnabled="true"
                    android:id="@+id/editTextClientName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is the java code:

```
if(t.getClientName().equals("")){
            editTextClientName.setError( "Client name is required!" );
            return false;
        }
```

[image: This is the result]

Answer (score 0):

You just made a simple mistake, Give your TextInputLayout an id and then call setError method on it instead of TextInputEditText.

Do this :

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

            android:id="@+id/textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:hint="@string/enter_client_name">


            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextClientName"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Java code :

```
if(t.getClientName().equals("")){
        textInputLayout.setError( "Client name is required!" );
        return false;
    }
```